# Not clear where pkg-config is finding information or how .pc files are named

Tags: debian, pkg-config

I followed a tutorial on GTK which used this command to generate the build flags:

```
$ pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0
```

This outputs coherent flags. From research, I have found that `pkg-config` searches for `.pc` files  in `/usr/lib/pkginfo`, `usr/share/pkgconfig`, in the `/local` equivalents, and in the folder indicated by the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` variable.

None of the folders contains the GTK file and the environment variable is not set. Where is `pkg-config` getting the flags?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It’s finding them in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/gtk+-3.0.pc` (assuming you’re on `amd64`). On Debian, `pkg-config` also searches the multi-arch directory for the target, *i.e.* `/usr/lib/$(dpkg-architecture -q DEB_TARGET_MULTIARCH)/pkgconfig`.

Answer (score 8):

There are a couple of nice tricks given in the man page for getting this information from `pkg-config` itself.

```
PKG-CONFIG DERIVED VARIABLES

       pc_path
              The default search path used by pkg-config  when  searching  for
              .pc files. This can be used in a query for the pkg-config module
              itself itself:
                $ pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config

       pcfiledir
              The installed location of the .pc file.  This  can  be  used  to
              query  the location of the .pc file for a particular module, but
              it can also be used to make .pc files relocatable.
```

So for example to see the actual search path for your system / architecture:

```
$ pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config | tr ':' '\n'
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
/usr/local/share/pkgconfig
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
/usr/lib/pkgconfig
/usr/share/pkgconfig
```

and to get the location where a particular package's `.pc` file is found

```
$ pkg-config --variable pcfiledir gtk+-3.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
```